# React setState for dynamic array

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react hook  to setState using dynamic key like this.
Final output should contains only unique key(no duplicate key)

My code:

```
const [sub, setSub] = React.useState();

setValue({
      [name]: { ...value, [key]: event.target.value }
});
```

Output got as:

```
{
  "0":"P","1":"r","2":"o","3":"d","4":"u","5":"c","6":"t","7":" ","8":"T","9":"y","10":"p","11":"e",
  "Assignee":"Mike","Product Type":"Product 2"
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
  "Assignee":"Mike",
  "Product Type":"Product 2"
}
```

Comment: Not sure whether this is your expectation, https://codesandbox.io/s/react-functional-component-forked-dsqen but hope this helps you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see in this example.

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
const [sub, setSub] = React.useState({
  this: 0,
  is: 0,
  the: 0,
  default: 0,
  state: 0
});
const handleOnClick = ({ target: { value = "this" } }) => {
  setSub((oldState) => ({
    ...oldState,
    [value]: oldState[value] + 1
  }));
};
return (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Hello R</h1>
    <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
    {
      Object.keys(sub).map((k, i)=>
        <div key={`${sub}_${i}`}>{sub[k]}</div>)
    }
    {Object.keys(sub).map((k, i) => (
      <button onClick={handleOnClick} key={i} value={k}>
        {k}
      </button>
    ))}
  </div>
);
}
```

you can achieve changing state dynamically in react using dynamics keys. Although i would use another approach. Separating each value in its independent getter and setter. With that when you update a value the other remains untouched. That way you get better performance. This is of course not always possible. Looking at your object maybe the first example would be the way to go.